# Need to extract value or text of cookie from array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, cookies

I have the following cookie:

```
{"CATEGORIES":[{"id":"21","text":"SOMEVALUE","operation":true,"type":"Categories"}],"SUBCATEGORIES":[],"SPECIALTIES":[]}
```

I need to be able to return the text represented by SOMEVALUE. The length of that text will not be static.

So far I've only been able to figure out how to retrieve the full value of the cookie using

```
jQuery.cookie('NAMEOFCOOKIE');
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSON.parse('{"CATEGORIES": [{"id":"21","text":"SOMEVALUE","operation":true,"type":"Categories"}],"SUBCATEGORIES":[],"SPECIALTIES":[]}').CATEGORIES[0].text
```

or

```
JSON.parse(jQuery.cookie('NAMEOFCOOKIE')).CATEGORIES[0].text
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the value of cookie in a variable say xx.

```
var xx={"CATEGORIES":[{"id":"21","text":"SOMEVALUE","operation":true,"type":"Categories"}],"SUBCATEGORIES":[],"SPECIALTIES":[]};
```

What you need will be available by simple `xx.CATEGORIES[0].text`

Answer (score 0):

```
var cookie_obj = JSON.parse(jQuery.cookie('NAMEOFCOOKIE'));

var category_text = cookie_obj.CATEGORIES[0].text;
```